# C++ static member of class template -- linker warning "multiple definition"

Tags: c++, templates, static-members, linker-warning

Let's say for some reason, I want to have a class template MyTemp with some static data member smDummyVar :

Mytemp.h

```
#ifndef MY_TEMP_H
#define MY_TEMP_H

template<class T>
class MyTemp{
...
private:
   static int smDummyVar;
   ...
};

#include "MyTemp.cpp"

#endif //MY_TEMP_H
```

Mytemp.cpp

```
...
template<class T> int MyTemp<T>::smDummyVar = 0;
...
```

Since the compiler requires that the definition and declaration of a template be at the same place, so I include MyTemp.cpp in MyTemp.h .

Now: I want to use MyTemp at many places and create objects using the template:

case1.cpp

```
#include "MyTemp.h"

void dummyfunc1(){
    MyTemp<int> myTemp1;
}
```

case2.cpp

```
#include "MyTemp.h"

void dummyfunc2(){
    MyTemp<int> myTemp2;
}
```

I won't get any error from the compiler, but I'd get warning from the linker:

```
"multiple definition for MyTemp<int>::smDummyVar" ... defined in invalid_group(case1.o) ... rejected in favour of symbol defined in ...(case2.o)
```

Question: how can I get rid of this warning ?

Thanks a lot in advance for your help !

====================================

inspired by one of the answers in this thread [Why can templates only be implemented in the header file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file)
I found the following solution:

i. remove `#include "MyTemp.cpp"` in MyTemp.h

ii. specialized.h

```
#include "MyTemp.h"
typedef MyTemp<int> MySpecialized;
```

iii. specialized.cpp

```
#include "MyTemp.cpp"
template class MyTemp<int>;
```

iv. give specialized.cpp to cmake file

v. include specilized.h in case1.cpp and case2.cpp

the "multiple definition" warning issued by the linker will go away.

Thank you guys for helping !

Comment: Just put everything in the header and use a `inline` for the definiiiton: `inline template<class T> int MyTemp<T>::smDummyVar = 0;`

Comment: Sorry, @πάνταῥεῖ, that duplicate you marked just isn't, because it effectively is everything in a header file. Since the .cpp is included in the .h, that split is irrelevant.

Comment: @Ulrich Sorry to disagree. The case that `#include "xxx.cpp"` shouldn't be included at the header and why is explained there IIRC.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ  : nope, that doesn't work.